# Delete Node in BST heap-use-after-free error

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

I'm trying to delete a node in BST iterative using in-ordered predecessor. But I kept getting heap-use-after-free-error.

AddressSanitizer: heap-use-after-free on address 0x603000000160 at pc 0x0000004088e6 bp 0x7ffe8255bb20 sp 0x7ffe8255bb18

```
class Solution {
public:
    TreeNode* deleteNode(TreeNode* root, int key) {
        TreeNode* myFind = find(root, key);
        if(!myFind) return root;
        if(myFind -> left == NULL && myFind -> right == NULL) {
            delete myFind;
            myFind == NULL;
        } else if(!myFind -> left && myFind -> right) {
            TreeNode* temp = myFind;
            myFind = myFind -> right;
            delete temp;
        } else if(myFind -> left && !myFind -> right) {
            TreeNode* temp = myFind;
            myFind = myFind -> left;
            delete temp;
        } else{
            TreeNode* iop = myFind -> left;
            while(iop -> right) {
                iop = iop -> right;
            }
            myFind-> val = iop->val;
            if(iop -> left) {
                TreeNode* temp = iop;
                iop = iop -> left;
                delete temp;
            } else {
                delete iop;
                iop = NULL;
            }
        }
        return root;
    }

    TreeNode* find(TreeNode*& root, int& key) {
        if(root == NULL) {
            return NULL;
        } else if(root -> val == key) {
            return root;
        } else if(key > root -> val) {
            return find(root -> right, key);
        } else {
            return find(root -> left, key);
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at these lines:

```
TreeNode* myFind = find(root, key);
...
delete myFind;
myFind == NULL;
```

(There are other paths in the code, but they work the same way.)

Suppose the root node is `A`, and `A.left` points to node `B`, and `find` returns a pointer to `B`. Then the code deletes `B`, and sets `myFind` (a variable local to the function) to `NULL`.

**`A.left` has not changed.** It still points to the location in the heap where `B` used to be, but that node has been deleted and that memory freed. The next time any code tries to dereference `A.left`, you'll get the error. It is `A.left` you must set to `NULL`. And yes, that means slightly more complicated code, it can't be helped.

Comment: Thanks for replying! But I did not use any recursive call here. So if it is a leaf node, I would just delete it. Where's the memory error?

Comment: @JimmyLiao: The memory error occurs when any code -- either in these functions or elsewhere -- dereferences the pointer which still points to the deleted node. If you doubt this, I suggest you prepare a [minimal complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that produces the error, and we can track it down.

Comment: https://leetcode.com/problems/delete-node-in-a-bst/  Sorry I don't use SO that often, but it's a leetcode problem and you can test the code there. Thanks!